# When using Filestream Filemode.Append does it overwrite what is lying next to the file?

Tags: c#, append, overflow, filestream, overwrite

Lets assume that exactly 1 byte after the File-1-EOF another file (file2) starts.

If I open up file 1 and use FileStream Filemode.Append, does it overwrite file2 or does it make another copy at a place where there is enough memory?

Thanks, in regards!

Edit:
For everyone after me: I forgot that you have a file system, which is split into chunks. Making this question nonsense!

Comment: I'd image that when you use a FileStream on a particular file path that only that file is modified. If not, that seems pretty detrimental to its use.

Comment: Yeah, but what if you edit it to have more bytes in the end?
You'd have to either make a copy or overwrite (which is bad)

Comment: That depends on the filesystem on the partition. This isn't like c/c++ RAM access where going over your memory limit bleeds into other information. Filesystems don't work like that, and while you _could_ have that sort of power if you wanted it, `FileStream` certainly will not corrupt other files when making modifications.

Comment: It would destroy your filesystem and corrupt your disk if this was possible with normal c# functions. There's are multiple APIs between Filestream and the disc sectors.

Comment: For everyone after me: I forgot that you have a file systems, which is split into chunks. Making this question nonsense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be laboring under the misapprehension that files are stored sequentially on disk, and that extending one file might overwrite parts of another file. This doesn't happen when you go via a filestream append in c#. The operating system will write the bytes you add however it likes, wherever it likes (and it likes to not overwrite other files) which is how files end up broken into smaller chunks (and why defragging  is thing) scattered all over the disk. None of this is of any concern to you, because the OS presents those scattered file fragments as a single contiguous stream of bytes to any program that wants to read them

Of course, if you wrote a program that bypassed the OS and performed low level disk access, located the end of the file and then blindly write more bytes into the locations after it then you would end up damaging other files, and even the OS's carefully curated filesystem .. but a .net file stream won't make that possible

TLDR; add your bytes and don't worry about it. Keeping the filesystem in order is not your job

Comment: That is actualyl right. The moment I asked this questions, it kind of was out of my brain that we have "clusters"... Thanks for reminding me again, this answer is actually right

Answer (score 0):

> If I open up file 1 and use FileStream Filemode.Append, does it overwrite file2 or does it make another copy at a place where there is enough memory?

Thankfully no.

Here's a brief overview why:

Your .NET C# code does not have direct OS level interaction.

Your code is compiled into byte-code and is interpreted at runtime by the .NET runtime.

During runtime your byte-code is executed by the .NET Runtime which is built mostly in a combination of C#/C/C++.

The runtime secures what it calls *SafeHandles*, which are wrappers around the file handles provided by what I can assume is `window.h`(for WIN32 applications at least), or whatever OS level provider for file handles you're architecture is running on.

The runtime uses these handles to read and write data using the OS level API.

It is the OS's job to ensure changes to `yourfile.txt`, using the handle it's provided to the runtime, only affects that file.

Files are not generally stored in memory, and as such are not subject to buffer overflows.

The runtime **may** use a buffer in memory to.. buffer your reads and writes but that is implemented by the runtime, and has no affect on the file and operating system.

Any attempt to overflow this buffer is safe-guarded by the runtime itself and the execution of your code will stop. Regardless, if a buffer overflow happened on this buffer successfully - no extra bytes will be written to the underlying handle. Rather the runtime would likely stop executing with a memory access violation, or general unspecified behavior.

The handle you're given is little more than a token that the OS uses to keep track which file you want to read or write bytes to.

If you attempt to write more bytes to a file than an architecture allows - most operating systems will have safe guards in place to end your process, close the file, or straight up send an interrupt to crash the system.

Comment: Quite a bit of what you mention isn't directly relevant: the operating system doesn't care if you overrun your buffer (at least as far as writing files is concerned). It simply ensures what is in the buffer goes to that file, and each file is segregated from any other. It doesn't need "safeguards", there is simply no mechanism for overflowing into the next file, the user-mode file system just isn't built that way